# Cannot launch an application, 'No such file or directory' but it exists

Tags: command-line, executable

The folder exists, the application has been made executable. 

But when i run it I get the following message:

> pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$ /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab
>   
> bash: /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab: No such file or directory
>   
> pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$

Thanks

**NOTE: AS SUGGESTED BELOW**

```
pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$ file /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab /bin/bash
/home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x22c8628796d72d721cf46293fe1d83b965de6df0, stripped
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x7ea55c6b94d32a06887081649ec990fd70700455, stripped
pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$
```

**NOTE: AS SUGGESTED BELOW**

```
pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~/Applications/ClipGrab$ ls -l
total 588
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pst007x pst007x 388096 Mar 26 14:50 clipgrab
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pst007x pst007x 194397 Feb 11 04:07 clipgrab-3.1.3.0.bz2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pst007x pst007x  15981 Feb 13 00:46 Clipgrab icon.jpg
pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~/Applications/ClipGrab$
```

**NOTE: AS SUGGESTED BELOW**

```
    pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$ cd /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/
    pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~/Applications/ClipGrab$ ./clipgrab
    bash: ./clipgrab: No such file or directory
    pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual case for this is trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system.
This should show you if that is the case:

```
file /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab /bin/bash
```

If it shows clipgrab to be 32-bit and /bin/bash to be 64-bit, the solution should be to install 32-bit libraries. You do this by installing the ia32-libs package

Comment: Output added to main description. Added libraries as suggested, rebooted, all worked ok. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/`
2. `./clipgrab`

Comment: Thanks, still same result: ... bash: ./clipgrab: No such file or directory –

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions set to on that file? You will need to make sure that the file is `readable` and `executable` to be able to run it.

For example, this file is only readable and writable by root:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 622 Aug 22  2009 test.py
```

To be able to run it as a normal user, it would need to have the readable and executable bits set, for all users. The permissions should instead look something like this when running `ls -l` in the terminal:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 622 Aug 22  2009 test.py
```

Comment: Thanks, all permissions seem ok: -rwxrwxrwx 1 pst007x pst007x 388096 Mar 26 14:50 clipgrab